# Can Conformal Mapping Techniques be used to study Axisymmetric Flows?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, symmetry, conformal-field-theory, flow

In fluid dynamics, I am aware that one usually uses conformal mapping techniques to study flows which are two-dimensional and was wondering if you could use them to study axisymmetric flows as well, or would this depend on whether one can find a particular plane which reduces the problem back to the 2D case?